# env: ‘export’: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, sudo

I have recieved this error and I don't know what is causing this error.

> bv-notifier@0.0.1 start /home/ubuntu/bustabit/bustabit-depositor
>   env $(cat .env | xargs) forever start daemon.js
>
> env: ‘export’: No such file or directory
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1013-aws npm ERR! argv
>   "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node"
>   "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/npm" "start" npm ERR!
>   node v7.10.0 npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0 npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code
>   ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR!
>   bv-notifier@0.0.1 start: `env $(cat .env | xargs) forever start
>   daemon.js` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the
>   bv-notifier@0.0.1 start script 'env $(cat .env | xargs) forever start
>   daemon.js'. npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js
>   and npm installed. npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem
>   with the bv-notifier package, npm ERR! not with npm itself. npm ERR!
>   Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm ERR!     env $(cat
>   .env | xargs) forever start daemon.js npm ERR! You can get information
>   on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs
>   bv-notifier npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls bv-notifier npm ERR! There is
>   likely additional logging output above.

Comment: You can add four spaces at the start of each line to get preformatted text.

Comment: Or highlight the terminal text and press Ctrl+K

Comment: @wjandrea what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I meant you can make the formatting in your post look better by copy-pasting the text from the terminal and applying formatting (as mentioned).

Comment: Well what were you trying to do when you got the error? The output seems to be telling you to report a bug against `bv-notifier`...